# Apply multiple condition in using jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I want to apply click event in this div

```
<input class="form_button_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request">
```

It should satisfy both this condition means should be of class `.form_button_submit` and `input[value='Submit Request']`

I want to do something like this :

```
$(".form_button_submit && input[value='Submit Request']").click(function() {
    alert("Nothing")
});
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: NEVER call anything in a form "submit" if you plan to submit the form using script (and if not, still not a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like:

```
$("input.form_button_submit[value='Submit Request']")
```

**Demo:**

You can see in the below demo only first button works, as it satisfies both this condition means should be of class `.form_button_submit` and `input[value='Submit Request']`

```js
$("input.form_button_submit[value='Submit Request']").click(function() {
    alert("Nothing")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form_button_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request">
<input class="form_button_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request2">
<input class="form_button_submit2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request">
```

Comment: I strongly recommend NOT to name anything in a form "submit"

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selectors can be used in JQuery with commas `,`

```
$(".form_button_submit, input[value='Submit Request']").click(function() {
    alert("Nothing")
});
```